# adding css style to certain li without nested ul

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add a class to list elements with a special class but NOT on their nested ul.

```
<div id="nav">    
    <ul>               
        <li class="closed top">Topic 1
            <ul>              
                <li class="closed top">Subtopic 1
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" id="k0" class="link active">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="k1" class="link inactive">Link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="closed top">Topic 2
            <ul>              
                <li class="closed top">Subtopic 1
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" id="l0" class="link inactive">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="l1" class="link inactive">Link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li> 
            </ul>
        </li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

If eg Link 1 is active, I want all the li's with 'top' class to change their color.

```
if ($('#nav a').hasClass('active')) {        
    $('li.top').addClass('textcolor');
}
```

Right now the style is appended to the every element and I only want the style on my .top li's.

Additionally, I want to remove that class when a link in another Topic menu gets active. (there can be only one active link, the previous one turns to inactive then, I already did that.).

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzLjm/2/), with some additional stuff though. jQuery function is at the bottom. The .textcolor style there is with a red background to see the changes directly.

EDIT: Nothing of the suggested answers are working. I don't know if I am missing something, but also if I try the code below in my fiddle it's just not working. Any ideas on this?

Comment: your 2nd level also has the class "top". you can use `ul>li` to only style the immediate children of a `ul`. if that doesn't work you may need to un-style the descendants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use child selector:

```
ul>li
```

This only affect li that are direct child of the ul.
You can use this selector in jquery too (look at http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: I tried that, but 
`if ($('#nav a').hasClass('active')) {        
    $('#nav > ul > li.top').addClass('textcolor');
}`
is not working.

Comment: I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NV5R/1/) and tried another approach. It works, but I'm not sure this is your goal. I think it would be better using a click event applied on a items

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this

```
if ($('#nav a.active').length) {
    $('#nav a.active').parents('.top').filter(function(){
        return $(this).parents('.top').length == 0
    }).addClass('textcolor')
}
```

it will, for each `<a>` that has `.active` class, inside `#nav`, find top most parent with class `top` and add `textcolor` class to that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, you could try adding a class to the other `li`s (that is, the ones that have no class in your example code) and define the attributes for that class that shouldn't change.

Basically, anything that you don't want the `li`s to inherit from their parents should be explicitly defined (color, background-color, text-decoration, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add another statement that sets the backcolour of all the children at the time.

```
if ($('#nav a').hasClass('active')) {        
    $('li.top').addClass('textcolor');
    $('li.top').children().addClass('notextcolor');
}
```

Obviously you will need another CSS class called `notextcolor` that has the style you want.

EDIT: - just noticed you have `top` on the 2nd level too - so this will only apply from the 3rd level down unless you change that.